# Get the contents/text present in dataURL from filereader API Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

How to read the contents inside the dataURL? As readAsDataURL is called first and then your reader.onload function called. If I used reader.readAsDataURL inside onload function. I get error as below:
    Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'readAsDataURL' on 'FileReader': parameter 1 is not of type 'Blob'.

sample code:https://jsfiddle.net/zzx4aeLg/3/

```
<input type='file' onchange='openFile(event)'>
    <script>
        var openFile = function(event) {
            var input = event.target;
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function() {
                debugger;
                var dataURL = reader.result;
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        };
    </script>
```

Comment: What are you trying to do, exactly? What in your page isn't working? The code looks fine to me

Comment: @Markasoftware
I finally think I got solution to the reading the content inside a file.

https://jsfiddle.net/3edkjrr0/3/